# Dynamically arranging objects in a panel

Tags: c#, dynamic, windows-forms-designer

So I'm fetching images from a website and storing them in the MostUsedHeroesAndImages. Then I'm trying to display them on a panel via dynamic creation of pictureboxes. How do I program it so the creation of pictureboxes starts at left=0 top=25, then when 10 images (with 50 pixels between each image) have been displayed it starts over at at left=0 top=200 to show another 10 images and so on making a grid of images? I currently have this code which displays all my images in a straight line going left to right with no gap between them. I tried setting a starting point, but then it just stores all the pictures on top of eachother. For how to make a gap between each image and make it skip a row when 10 have been displayed I have no idea.

```
public void RunMeta()
    {

        foreach(var mostPickedHero in FetchDataFromDota2Site.MostUsedHeroesAndImages)
        {
            PictureBox temp = new PictureBox();
            temp.ImageLocation = mostPickedHero.ImageSource;
            temp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            temp.Left = temp.Width * panel1.Controls.Count;
         //   temp.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(left, top);
            panel1.Controls.Add(temp);
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will probably help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel) instead of a simple Panel (panel1).
You will need only to set [Margin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.margin) on the PictureBox controls to make the gaps.
This is a ready-to-use solution that involve no code logic to make the pictures wrap. It also works anytime the panel is resized.

Default behavior of FlowLayoutPanel is to lay controls horizontally from left to right (see [FlowDirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.flowdirection)) and wrap to a new line automatically (see [WrapContents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.wrapcontents)).

Keep in mind that when the number of child controls (your pictures) grow very much, FlowLayoutPanel can become slow.